# Error al correr una ventana Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: Error]

Necesito una mano y eso que este es un ejercicio que sigo con una tutorial y ya esta saltando como loco, no me quiero imaginar si quiero hacer un programa propio XD

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, da un [tour] y revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad.Cualquier código debe ir en forma de texto.

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el código como texto ya que en la imagen no es legible, edita tu pregunta y agrega màs información, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te ha saltado una `NullPointerException`, esta excepción suele aparecer cuando creas un objeto y, al llamar a una propiedad del mismo o al objeto en sí no tiene un valor asignado, por lo que java le asigna el valor `null`. Suele arreglarse agregando condicionales que comprueben que la información que intentas obtener no sea `null`.

Aunque si quieres un consejo, ya que veo que estás empezando, has empezado por lo último que se aprende y te dejas todo un mundo por el camino. Empieza aprendiendo a hacer programas sencillos(sumas, bucles, factoriales etc...), aprende los tipos de datos,bucles, condicionales, arrays, programación orientada a objetos y manejo de errores. Cuando aprendas eso y lo entiendas, entonces ya le metes mano a las ventanas, o mejor dicho, interfaces gráficas, ya que un programa no tiene porqué necesariamente tener una interfaz gráfica, las interfaces gráficas están destinadas al usuario final.

Te recomiendo un canal de youtube, programación ATS, el chico hace unos tutoriales buenísimos, te va enseñando paso a paso con ejercicios que puedes hacer tú mismo y cubre hasta temas avanzados en java te lo dejo aquí: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7QoKU6bj1QbXQuNIjan82Q

Mucho ánimo y mucha suerte. Esto de la programación puede ser frustrante a veces cuando algo no sale, pero la sensación de felicidad cuando terminas algo y funciona es muchísimo más gratificante. Además cambia tu manera de ver el mundo, porque sientes que estás ayudando a construir algo enorme que surgió de la nada.

Comment: ya lo resolví, el problema estaba en que leía mal la ruta de unas imágenes, de todas formas aun me intriga el saber porque con algunas imágenes solo tomaba como valido el "/images/nombreImagen.png" y en otras imágenes debía de poner toda la ruta "C:\\Users\\..."